# Cyclic Reference Error When Trying to Reference Previous Data in Table (FrontAPI)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In Power BI's Advanced Query Editor, what I'm trying to do is:

1. Get the max value of the `Event_Emitted_At` column from a previously queried API call (the table has been previously generated and has data in it)
2. Use the value from step 1 as the `after` parameter for an API call (as the API allows you to filter for results `Emitted` `after` a particular Unix timestamp.

Right now, I'm getting a `A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation.` error.

This is a sample of the previously queried table:

[image: previouslyQueriedTable]

What I have so far is this project/query structure:

[image: getLatestEmittedAt]

This above function should just grab the max value from the `FrontEmailEvents[Events_Emitted_At]` table/column.

[image: getAPIResults]

This above function grabs the results of an API call, making use of Pagination.

Now with those two functions in place, we can start a `while` loop to query for all `events` from the API between the `after` parameter and `before` the current time's timestamp:

[image: MainQueryBody]

The code "looks" ok, but I think it's throwing the cyclic reference error because it's assuming that the query is starting from scratch every time? So, it doesn't "know" or realize that there's already data stored in the `FrontEmailEvents` table from a query that was run on a previous day.

How can I make use of an "old" datapoint to use in a future query?

(In case you haven't noticed, this is using the Front API).

**UPDATE**

It's the `_func_get_latest_emitted_at` that's throwing the error, so the function that's trying to grab the `max` value of the `FrontEmailEvents` table is what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to return a record, so you have to do this

```
() as record=> let z=[A=List.Max(Table1[a])] in z
```

not this

```
() as record=> let z=List.Max(Table1[a]) in z
```

Or instead, return a number, not a record

```
() as number=> let z=List.Max(Table1[a]) in z
```

That said, not sure why you are bothering with the function at all since you are not passing any parameters. Just directly reference the List.Max where you need it